# Ordering a string based on another string

Tags: python

I'm at a place in my code where I need to make the order of the contents in one string equal the order of the other. So say you put the string `'this place'` into my function you will get `TIPAEhslc` returned and I want to change the order of the contents of that to match the original input string without the spaces, so: `'ThIsPlAcE'`. So, in my code, using `no_space` to order `s_combine` I know I've figure this out before but I can't remember how and I've been stuck on this ! This is my code so far:

```
def r_string(string):
    s_even = []
    s_odd = []
    s_compare = []
    s_split = [[x] for x in string.split()]
    for i in s_split:
        for u in i:
            s = enumerate(u)
            for j,k in s:
                if j % 2 == 0:
                    s_even.append(k)
                else:
                    s_odd.append(k)
    s_even = ''.join(s_even).upper()
    s_odd = ''.join(s_odd).lower()
    s_combine = s_even + s_odd
    no_space = string.replace(" ","")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def r_string(s):
    n = list()
    for i, a in enumerate(s.replace(' ', '')):
        if i%2==0:
            n.append(a.upper())
        else:
            n.append(a)

    return ''.join(n)

 print(r_string('this place'))
```

Output:

```
#ThIsPlAcE
```

Edit:

I guess you r looking for this....

```
def r_string(s1, s2):
    #s1 is string to order
    #s2 string map to follow
    map_ = {s.lower():s.istitle() for s in s2}
    new_string = ''.join([s.upper() if map_[s] else s for s in s1.replace(' ', '')])

    return new_string

print(r_string('string me', 'TrinGsMe'))
```

Output:

```
#sTrinGMe
```

Comment: so this is great, it works for this stage of my code and makes most of my code look blocky and unwarranted but I still need the functionality of ordering a string by another string.

Comment: so if I had `'hOij'` and I want this to be in the order of `'ohij'` but  like `'Ohij'` since the o is captial in `'hOij'`. it needs to retain the same character case (upper or lower) while taking the ordering of the ordering string